# what's 'should' in Rspec? Why does `should redirect_to` work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Rspec has a lot of magics. I can't find out what `should` is and how to use it.

```
response.should redirect_to(some_path)
```

The [Rdoc](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/2.4.0/Kernel%3ashould) says `should` can be called with `==`, `===`, `~=`, and a matcher(what is it?). I guess `redirect_to(some_path)` is the matcher.

But what does it mean? This `redirect_to` is the same as the `ActionController::Redirecting#redirect_to`? Can `should` know whether Rails calls this method?

And the other things...

```
should render_template
should have_text
```

Is render_template the `ActionView::LogSubscriber#render_template`? So any Rails method can be attached after `should`? Moreover, Rails doesn't have the method `have_text`, so what is it? Why does `should` know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that `redirect_to` is a different thing. The one you're using when doing `should redirect_to()` is this matcher - http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/dir/matchers/redirect-to-matcher

Same with [render_template](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/dir/matchers/render-template-matcher)

Comment: So there are only three matchers in Rspec 2: `redirect_to`, `render_template` and `be_a_new`? Or there is a complete list somewhere?

Comment: There are several. Most of them are documented here - http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations